# View all values of localized Component field

Tags: core-service, cme, gui-extensions, custom-page

I would like to find out if a field has been localized and Translated in 1 Component localized in about 30 child Publications.  Has anyone written a Core Service Custom Page or GUI Extension to do this?

Or, is there a way in the normal default interface to get this info?

I have written a classic ASP custom page in version 5.x that provided this info, but did not port it (yet) to the new Core Service API.

The user would like to save some time rather than manually opening 30 Components and checking each one individually.

Comment: You're looking for _just_ that field and not whether the whole component is localized, right? The fastest way to see all the Components would be the BluePrint viewer. If going for a GUI extension, knowing that field from a parent item or within the BP viewer might be a good fit. For a generic approach, a "spreadsheet" view of Components (in a folder or an item and its children) would be nice. ;-)